# Absolute positioned slideshow problems

Tags: html, css, css-position

so I'm trying to create a slideshow, by using absolute positioning to stack the pictures on top of each other, but the problem I'm having is the text from below the slideshow is also getting stacked on top of the pictures. I tried putting the pictures inside a wrapper div, whose position was relative, but that didn't do anything. If anyone see's the problem, I'd really appreciate some help.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="imageDiv">
    <div id="mainImage">
            <img class="imagePositioning" id="slideshowImg1"  src="images/tbrownMain.jpg" alt="Image of Terrell Brown" ></img>
            <img  class="imagePositioning" id="slideshowImg2" src="images/giantsMain.jpg" alt="Image of Giants" ></img>
            <img  class="imagePositioning" id="slideshowImg3"  src="images/kobeMain.jpg" alt="Image of Kobe" ></img>
            <img  class="imagePositioning" id="slideshowImg4"  src="images/nashMain.jpg" alt="Image of Nash" ></img>
            <img class="imagePositioning" id="slideshowImg5" src="images/tebowMain.jpg" alt="Image of Tim Tebow" ></img>
    </div>
    <div id="contentText">
            <a id="introText">Tim Tebow talks about Aaron Hernandez</a>
            <p id="detailsPar">Tim Tebow...</p>

    </div>
    <table id="mediaMenu">
    <tr>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="doEverything(0)">
            <table> 
                <tr> <td class="subTitle"> Tebow Talks </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img style="opacity:1.0" id="sub0" src="images/tebow.jpg" alt="Tim Tebow"></img></td></tr> 
            </table>
            </a></td>
//...4 more nested tables in same way
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
#mainImage {
position:relative;
}
#imageDiv {
border: 5px solid black;
width:70%;
position:relative;
}
.imagePositioning  {
position:absolute;
}

#contentText {
color:orange;
float:right;
position:absolute;
left:43%;
width:26%;
top:2%;
}
#mediaMenu td {
margin:3px;
padding:0px;
width:20%;
color:blue;
font-family: Chalkduster, Verdana, Sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't combine floats and absolute positioning. Use pixels, not percents.

Comment: Aren't percents the best way to make the site responsive though?

Comment: They are, but in this case the position of the text needs to be a known value compared to the photo's position.

Comment: You should know that:
#id {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 20;
}
apart from the position is this the same:
#id {
positon: relative;
left: 20px;
}

Comment: isn't it the other way around? Margins with relative and left:20 with absolute. But yah I get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the z-index lower for whatever div wraps the text. assuming it's contentText use:

```
#contentText  {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

if this isn't your exact solution fiddling with z-indices should be your solution in any case...

Comment: changing the z-index just moved the pictures to the front, but now the text is stuck behind the pictures

Comment: "but the problem I'm having is the text from below the slideshow is also getting stacked on top of the pictures." From that I assumed you wanted this... instead just put whatever text you want behind the images with a z-index of -1

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:

1. As @diodeus pointed out, don't use absolute positioning with float
2. I think you meant to close your `#imageDiv` before the table
3. You need to clear `#mediaMenu {clear:both}`

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tc36z/1/

Comment: So after doing these 3 things, The text is now to the right of the main image, which is where I wanted it to be, but the 5 bottom images are still on top of the main image. I did the {clear:both}, and that moved the row of images down a little bit, it didn't affect it much.

Comment: Did you close the #imageDiv `</div>` before the opening table tag? And remove the `</div>` from the end of your HTML?

Comment: I did. The best way I can think of doing it now is, as'Doctype html' suggested, just using margin-top to bring the mediaMenu images down below the main image.

Comment: Does the jsFiddle not look the way you want (table below the images, with "Tim Tebow talks..." to the right of images?

Comment: Yah that is essentially what I'm looking for, but I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code just to see how it would work on my browser, and what yours is doing is putting the mediaMenu img at the top with the main image below

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Using lots of absolute positioning and percentages to get everything working. I'm not sure of the exact layout you were going for so I just took a guess

```
This requires code for me to post an answer
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3FNg/